# Loading CSV data into MySQL in Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, csv

I am new to Python but have to skip few lessons to come to this topic.

I am using the following code:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'scmetrics-rds-rw.db.amazon.com',
port = 3306,
user = "s",
passwd = '',
db = 'mydb'
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader('h:\Depreciation-Reconstructed\test.csv')#Read the csv
for row in csv_data:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO TestTable(ID,Name,Age,Student(Yes/No) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)',row)

cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
```

However I am having an error which says:

> 'query = query % args
>   TypeError : Not enough arguments for format string

Comment: You can use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to directly import CSV data and this is usually way faster than reading it manually and converting it to statements.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a parentheses in your code after (Yes/No):
    `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO TestTable(ID,Name,Age,Student(Yes/No) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)',row)`